# Javascript For Cross Browser Detection of Incognito Mode (Private Browsing)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari, microsoft-edge

I am trying to create a cross browser javascript that detects whether or not the visitor is using Incognito Mode, and gives a alert message if the user visits the page in normal mode.

Currently I have a script, that works just fine on Chrome and Opera, But I need to get it work on all the other browsers as well like firefox, safari, Edge etc.

My script (Working on Chrome and Opera) is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
function main() {
  var fs = window.RequestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
  if (!fs) {
     alert("check failed!");
    return;
  }
  fs(window.TEMPORARY, 100, function(fs) {
    alert("You are not using Incognito Mode!");
  });
}
main();

}//]]> </script>
```

Please help me write a single script like this to give the same alert results in all the major web browsers.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I've finally made a working script for Firefox as well. The code is as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var db;
var request = indexedDB.open("MyTestDatabase");
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1)
{
  alert("You are not using Incognito Mode!");
};
};</script>
```

I've used the "if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1)" function so that it executes only on firefox, and not in chrome or any other browser.

**UPDATE:**

Ok another accomplishment! I've successfully written the script for Safari as well. Here it is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
try { localStorage.test = 2; } catch (e) {
}
if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) 
{
if (localStorage.test = "true") {
alert("You are not using Incognito Mode!");
}
}
</script>
```

Again, I've used "if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0)" function so that it executes only on Safari, and not in any other browser.

Now I need help in writing script only for Edge browser.

Comment: 'm unable to do it for firefox using indexedDB. And there is no single script out there that achieves this.

Comment: Not working on Chrome 58

Comment: @SidneydeMoraes It is working for me on Chrome 63

Comment: @cody thanks for your reply but my comment is 6 months old. You can disregard it.

Answer (score 0):

There is this solution I found [here](https://gist.github.com/cou929/7973956):

I just copied it below in case it gets removed.

```
function retry(isDone, next) {
    var current_trial = 0, max_retry = 50, interval = 10, is_timeout = false;
    var id = window.setInterval(
        function() {
            if (isDone()) {
                window.clearInterval(id);
                next(is_timeout);
            }
            if (current_trial++ > max_retry) {
                window.clearInterval(id);
                is_timeout = true;
                next(is_timeout);
            }
        },
        10
    );
}

function isIE10OrLater(user_agent) {
    var ua = user_agent.toLowerCase();
    if (ua.indexOf('msie') === 0 && ua.indexOf('trident') === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    var match = /(?:msie|rv:)\s?([\d\.]+)/.exec(ua);
    if (match && parseInt(match[1], 10) >= 10) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function detectPrivateMode(callback) {
    var is_private;

    if (window.webkitRequestFileSystem) {
        window.webkitRequestFileSystem(
            window.TEMPORARY, 1,
            function() {
                is_private = false;
            },
            function(e) {
                console.log(e);
                is_private = true;
            }
        );
    } else if (window.indexedDB && /Firefox/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
        var db;
        try {
            db = window.indexedDB.open('test');
        } catch(e) {
            is_private = true;
        }

        if (typeof is_private === 'undefined') {
            retry(
                function isDone() {
                    return db.readyState === 'done' ? true : false;
                },
                function next(is_timeout) {
                    if (!is_timeout) {
                        is_private = db.result ? false : true;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    } else if (isIE10OrLater(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
        is_private = false;
        try {
            if (!window.indexedDB) {
                is_private = true;
            }                 
        } catch (e) {
            is_private = true;
        }
    } else if (window.localStorage && /Safari/.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
        try {
            window.localStorage.setItem('test', 1);
        } catch(e) {
            is_private = true;
        }

        if (typeof is_private === 'undefined') {
            is_private = false;
            window.localStorage.removeItem('test');
        }
    }

    retry(
        function isDone() {
            return typeof is_private !== 'undefined' ? true : false;
        },
        function next(is_timeout) {
            callback(is_private);
        }
    );
}
```